# How to compare a columnvalue of a row accessed by rowindex and columnname?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I just wanna check if the value in myColumn of row at index i isn't 'X'. I tested the indexing - it works. But  why I get

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

with this line of code:

```
df.loc[i].myColumn != 'X'
```

or

```
df.loc[i, 'myColumn'] != 'X'
```

Sorry if this is a simple question but I am confused.
Why a column of a row is type of pandas series here?

Comment: 2nd line of code should work... what error do you get from that?

Comment: As it is edited right now, both should work. Can you provide a full example? i.e. a small dataframe that causes this error

Comment: the same @ChrisA .I wanna provide some exmple in a few minutes

Comment: is `i` a scaler value here or is it a list of indices?

Comment: Both must work. Maybe you have multiple rows with index i ? "Why a pandas series here"? --> It's what you did, you created a series with df.loc[i].myColumn != 'X'... it's a series of just one row... not impressed :-)

Comment: but it is row.column @FrancescoZambolin

Comment: Hi, not that. the comparison made the series !=; left part != right part --> series